# Is there any way to have inheritance between Enums?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I would like to have inheritance between some of the enums I define.

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
/**
 * @enum {!number}
 */
var MyBaseEnum = {
    IS_VALID         : 0b00000001,
    UNDER_VALIDATION : 0b00000010,
    SUBMITTING       : 0b00000100
};

/**
 * @enum {!number}
 * @extends {MyBaseEnum}
 */
var MyChildEnum = {
    AN_ODDBALL_STATE      : 0b00001000,
    ANOTHER_ODDBALL_STATE : 0b00010000
};

goog.inherits(MyChildEnum, MyBaseEnum);

/**
 * @param  {!MyBaseEnum} myEnum
 * @return {!string}
 */
function iExpectBaseEnum (myEnum) {
    switch (myEnum) {
        case MyBaseEnum.IS_VALID:
            return "It's valid, man!";
        case MyBaseEnum.UNDER_VALIDATION:
            return "Chill, I'm working on it.";
        case MyBaseEnum.SUBMITTING:
            return "Under submission, bro.";
        default:
            return 'WAT';
    }
};

/**
 * @param  {!MyChildEnum} myEnum
 * @return {!string}
 */
function iExpectChildEnum (myEnum) {
    switch (myEnum) {
        case MyChildEnum.AN_ODDBALL_STATE:
            return 'Dunno.';
        case MyChildEnum.ANOTHER_ODDBALL_STATE:
            return 'Dunno, bro.';
        // Accessing parent's IS_VALID would be nice through MyChildEnum.
        case MyChildEnum.IS_VALID:
            return "It's valid, man!";
        // But also would be nice to have it work with paren'ts value.
        case MyBaseEnum.UNDER_VALIDATION:
            return "Chill, I'm working on it.";
        case MyBaseEnum.SUBMITTING:
            return "Under submission, bro.";
        default:
            return 'WAT';
    }
};
```

At the moment I just can't find a way to have inheritance between my enumerations **AND** still have them behave like enumerations (I could do an awful ugly stinky hack of implementing my own enum system with generics, but... yuck... + I would lose a lot of juice from the compiler.

Is there any way to have inheritance between my enums or somehow solve the conceptual problem of enumeration specificity and extension?

Comment: You mean like `Object.assign(MyChildEnum, MyBaseEnum)`

Comment: Yea, Sort of. Basically anything that the compiler would eat. For the `Object.assign` approach I still get compiler errors (using gcc advanced) `Bad type annotation. type annotation incompatible with other annotations. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Bad-Type-Annotation for more information.` and `element IS_VALID does not exist on this enum
        case MyChildEnum.IS_VALID:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that using [Google Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) we can't have inheritance between enums.

The basis of my assumption is, that Java doesn't allow an enum inherit another one (though there is room for some nastiness using interfaces), and [Google Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) seems to be heavily inspired by Java.